# Why is setTimeout not running? (scope chain)

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I'm trying to run `setTimeout` within a function so that after one second, and the selected image will change.

In short, when I press the space bar, my program should:

- change the image to a different image (working)
- maintain the negative y-trajectory of the image (working)
- Wait one second, and call a method that changes the image (not working)

Here's my code:

```
    jump() {
        console.log("space bar pressed to jump");
        this.setDirection(Constants.SKIER_DIRECTIONS.JUMP_ONE);
        turnDown = () => { this.setDirection(Constants.SKIER_DIRECTIONS.DOWN); }
        setTimeout(turnDown, 1000);
     }
```

Instead of going back to the original image, the animation image sticks around indefinitely.

Here's the error message I'm getting:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: turnDown is not defined
```

I've looked at similar posts and their structure is very similar to mine, but perhaps it's something to do with my syntax (arrow function) for `turnDown`?

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe function hoisting since that looks like an implicit global? Try declaring it as (this looks like a class) a class function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign `turnDown` to something that doesn't exist - just add a `var` before it - `var turnDown = ...`

Comment: `var` is basically old school now. Use `let` or `const` if it's not reassigned

Comment: It's JS, so best to be safe - I'm 100% Typescript now, and quite agree :-P

Comment: Working - thank you. I'll have to incorporate clearInterval as well to smooth up the animation but this answers this particular question

Comment: @Rycochet not sure what the point of your comment is, but if arrow functions and member methods are being used, `let` and `const` can also be used.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I've not used `var` anywhere in literally years - but it's not *wrong* to use it, so while I quite agree (and in this case it doesn't even need a temporary variable as it's a `const` in that snippet), it's also not the point of the problem - though to my mind Javascript in itself is more of a problem than `var` - strongly typed is a far better way to go!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is running in *strict mode* implicitly because of the `class` declaration (I suspect you are inside a `class` body), so an assignment to a previously undeclared variable is illegal, hence the exception. In non strict mode the assignment would have created a global variable. If you refactor with a `const` / `var` / `let` declaration this will be fine. You could also inline the function declaration, and use a `function` keyword declaration allowing you to have a name for this function and a better stacktrace should it throw.